# Needed help to build caml Query with multiple <And>

Tags: list-view, caml-query, sharepoint-addin, object-model

I am getting a query from list view by view.Query i got the following

```
<QUERY>
   <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="100"><FieldRef Name="AlertGrp" /></GroupBy>
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="PriorityNoLink" Ascending="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef Name="match_time" Ascending="FALSE" />
   </OrderBy>
   <Where>
       <And>
           <And>
              <And>
                  <Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Text">ACH Alert</Value></Neq>
                  <Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Text">Check Fraud</Value></Neq>
              </And>
              <IsNull><FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" /></IsNull>
           </And>
           <Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq>
       </And>
    </Where>
</QUERY>
```

I want to add one more condition something like

```
<Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-5" />       </Value></Geq>
```

I added after AlertType

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq>
</And>
```

and start tag `<And>` added in the beginning along with `<And><And><And>`

But showing wrong result. Kindly help me where I can add the new condition.

Comment: You are saying "wrong result". If the CAML query is not properly formatted (e.g., <And> tag in the wrong place) then you should get an error. If you don't get an error, what exactly is the wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Where>
    <And>
       <And>
           <And>
              <And>
                  <Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Text">ACH Alert</Value></Neq>
                  <Neq><FieldRef Name="Category" /><Value Type="Text">Check Fraud</Value></Neq>
              </And>
              <IsNull><FieldRef Name="Close_x0020_Reason" /></IsNull>
           </And>
           <Eq><FieldRef Name="AlertType" /><Value Type="Text">Alert</Value></Eq>
       </And>
       <Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-5" />       </Value></Geq>
   </And>
</Where>
```

should work

Comment: He said "I added after AlertType ...". I was expecting his code to already look like your. ^_^

Comment: Me too, but if it did, I also would expect it to work ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this query in caml query builder it is showing result bt not the correct one. Am getting the first caml query from SpView.Query// but if i place the spview.Query value in the caml builder showing wrong data meantime in list it is showing perfect.

Comment: So I guess the problem is not the structure of the query, but more that the query is not correct for your needs

Comment: I would suggest that you use CAMLDesigner or U2U caml builder to build the query - then you can select the fields and generate the where-clause less error-prone.

CAMLDesigner: http://sharepoint.biwug.be/CamlDesigner/CamlDesigner.zip